# How to run custom PHP in a reaction rule in D8?

Tags: 8, rules

Have recently installed & then patched the Rules module to get it working in D8. I need to run an action which executes some PHP e.g when an order in Commerce is completed.

In D7 this is done by selecting Add action -> Execute custom PHP code, but in the D8 version I can't find a similar option. I'm having trouble finding any documentation for this feature.

How can this be accomplished in Drupal 8?

Comment: There's a reason for that. https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1203886 
If you want to run PHP code, you should write a custom module.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong thanks. I'm trying to migrate the config of an existing D7 site which unfortunately uses custom PHP code in reaction rules. Was hoping for a simple way to run that code.

Comment: I guess you'll have to migrate the code to custom actions or conditions first, then edit the rules accordingly. Haven't tried it, would guess it's a bit of a pain.

Comment: @Alfred thanks, appreciated. Painful or not, the alternative is "doesn't work" so I guess I'm in for some pain :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When looking at this thread [execute custom php code in rules](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2017-06-23/rules-execute-custom-php-code-in-drupal-8), it seems like it is not possible in Drupal 8.

If you want to `execute php code` in rules, you must create a custom action. Here is a guide how to create a custom rules action, [custom rules action](http://precessionmedia.com/blog/how-create-custom-rules-action).

The code to create a rules action:

```
<?php

/**
 * Implement hook_rules_action_info().
 */
function my_module_rules_action_info() {
  return array(
    'my_module_rules_action_create_hashed_string' => array(
      'label' => t('Create hashed string'),
      'group' => t('Custom'),
      'parameter' => array(
        'string' => array(
          'type' => 'text',
          'label' => t('String to be hashed'),
          'description' => t('Enter a value for a string that will be hashed using the md5 hash-algorithm.'),
        ),
        'length' => array(
          'type' => 'integer',
          'label' => t('The length of the returned string'),
          'description' => t('Enter a number for the length of the hashed string that will be created.'),
        ),
        'algorithm' => array(
          'type' => 'text',
          'label' => t('Algorithm'),
          'description' => t('Select a hash algorithm.'),
          'options list' => 'my_module_algorithm_options',
          'restriction' => 'input',
        ),
      ),
      'provides' => array(
        'hashed_string' => array(
          'type' => 'text',
          'label' => t('Hashed string'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

// A helper function to provide us with a list of algorithms
function my_module_algorithm_options() {
  $algorithms = array();

  $algorithms['md4'] = t('md4');
  $algorithms['md5'] = t('md5');

  return $algorithms;
}

// This callback creates the hashed string by using the parameters provided through rules' UI
function my_module_rules_action_create_hashed_string($string, $length, $algorithm) {
  if ($length <= 0) {
    // For anything below or equal zero lets return the default value.
    $string = hash('md5', $string);
  } else {
    $string = substr(hash($algorithm, $string), 0, $length);
  }

  return array(
    'hashed_string' => $string,
  );
}
```

Comment: The original poster asked for a D8 solution. Using hook_rules_action_info() only works in D7.